# Python multiprocessing pool, join; not waiting to go on?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

(1) I'm trying to use `pool.map` followed by `pool.join()`, but python doesn't seem to be waiting for `pool.map` to finish before going on past the `pool.join()`. Here's a simple example of what I've tried:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

foo = {1: []}

def f(x):
    foo[1].append(x)
    print foo

def main():
    pool = Pool()
    pool.map(f, range(100))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print foo

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The printed output is just `{1: []}`, as if python just ignored the `join` command and ran `print foo` before it had a chance to run `f`. The intended result is that `foo` is `{1:[0,1,...,99]}`, and using the ordinary built-in python `map` gives this result. Why is the pooled version printing `{1: []}`, and how can I change my code to make it print the intended result?

(2) Ideally I'd also like to define `foo` as a local variable in `main()` and pass it to `f`,
but doing this by making `foo` the first argument of `f` and using

`pool.map(functools.partial(f, foo), range(100))`

produces the same output. (and possibly also has the problem that each process now has its own copy of `foo`?) Though again, it works using the normal `map` instead.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is not the correct way to use `map`.

1. Using a global variable that way is absolutely wrong. Processes do not share the same memory (normally) so every `f` will have his own copy of `foo`. To share a variable between different processes you should use a `Manager`
2. Function passed to `map` are, usually, expected to return a value.

I suggest you to read some [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).

However here is a dummy example of how you could implement it:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

foo = {1: []}

def f(x):
    return x

def main():
    pool = Pool()
    foo[1] = pool.map(f, range(100))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print foo

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You may also do something like `pool.map(functools.partial(f, foo), range(100))` where `foo` is a `Manager`.

Comment: But why, in the original program, python doesn't wait for pool.map to finish before going on past the pool.join()?

Comment: Python waits for it, but the `foo` of the parent process didn't change. Every child process in the Pool modify its own copy of `foo`, not the one that gets printed at the end of the main.

Comment: Why do you need `pool.join()` if you use the `pool.map()` function that blocks? https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map

Comment: Calling `pool.close()` and `pool.join()` will ensure that not only the `map` has terminated (as you noted it is blocking), but also that the processes in the pool have been terminated and their resources freed. Not something that you absolutely need to do, but nice anyway if you don't need them anymore.

Comment: This is a good answer because you can use `join` in case you use `main()` in a `for_loop`