# Python's multiprocessing.Pool spawns new processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a simple question about the multiprocessing module.  I am using multiprocessing.Pool's `map()` function to speed up execution of self-written code on my local machine.  However, this code is run in an iterative loop and I find additional Python processes spawned in my machine with every iteration of the loop. (This is a problem because the system slowly grinds to a halt).  Here's a simple example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os

nthreads = 2
for ii in xrange(5):
    pool = Pool(processes=nthreads)  # (in my code, Pool is inside a pickleable function.)
    runningProcesses = os.popen('ps | grep ython').readlines()
    nproc = len(runningProcesses)
    print "After iteration %i there were %i Python processes running!" % (ii, nproc)
```

The output is:

```
After iteration 0 there were 5 Python processes running!
After iteration 1 there were 7 Python processes running!
After iteration 2 there were 9 Python processes running!
After iteration 3 there were 11 Python processes running!
After iteration 4 there were 13 Python processes running!
```

How should I arrange my code to avoid spawning many new Python processes?  I am running Python 2.7.6, which has multiprocessing v0.70a1, and am on a 4-core MacBook Pro running OSX 10.8.5.

Comment: You are creating a new multiprocessing pool of workers in ever iteration. Are you are trying to do is use the same pool of N workers across all the iterations?

Comment: Tom: your question was a bit garbled, and since I'm new to multiprocessing I'm not sure what you mean.  My only goals are (1) to be able to use multiprocessing to speed up the execution of my (scientific, data-crunching) code and (2) not spawn many subprocesses.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, it was a bad edit! You are creating a new Pool of workers in every iteration. E.g. in the second iteration, you have the original pool of 2 workers, then you create a new Pool with 2 more workers. In the 3rd iteration, you create a 3rd Pool of 2 more workers. Do you want to use the same pool of N workers across all the iterations?

Comment: The other issue might be that you are not .join() ing your pool workers when you are finished with them? See the top answer here for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914828/python-multiprocessing-pool-join-not-waiting-to-go-on

Comment: Tom: I'm indifferent as to whether I "use the same pool of N workers" or not -- I just want to stop the unstoppable buildup of subprocesses.  Adding `pool.close()` and then `pool.join()` within my sub-function seems to accomplish this, so it seems that this is the solution I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments - the worker processes in the pool are not being closed/joined, so they never terminate. The top answer here shows how to clean up the pool when you no longer need it: [Python multiprocessing pool, join; not waiting to go on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914828/python-multiprocessing-pool-join-not-waiting-to-go-on)

As a side note, if you are creating large numbers of workers and using them to perform very short/quick jobs, then you may find that the performance suffers - there is an overhead for the OS to create and destroy processes. If that is the case, then you should look at using a single Pool throughout your application.

Comment: As I noted above: adding pool.close() and then pool.join() within my sub-function seems to stop the endless proliferation of Python subprocesses, so it seems that this is the solution I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put the `pool = Pool(processes=nthreads)` above `for` loop

Comment: The problem is that the call to `Pool()` occurs within a function of my code. Each time the function is executed, additional processes are spawned.  Or do you mean that I should be passing a pool object between my primary script and the various subfunctions?

Comment: @Kreuzfeld It sounds like you need to show us more of your *actual* code, so we can see how your function is getting called, and what you're actually doing with the `Pool` object.

Comment: Pool() can't be in a loop because each time the loop iterates it creates new workers. You need the Pool() to be placed before the script starts any operation with a loop. So if you have a function that is executed more then once you should place the Pool() in some place before that function executes.

Comment: Vizjerei, do you mean I should be passing the pool object as an argument to my function?  [Pool can't be "before the script starts" because there is nothing "before" the script... Pool has to be initialized somewhere, either within the function or earlier in my script before the sub-function is called.]

Comment: Not before the main script but before the loop on the function you seam to have. The Pool() can't be in any loop. If you provide more code it would be easier to explain.