# How to let multiprocessing wait a bit?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

Now, I have a following function test()

```
def test():
    f1(par)  # extremely time consuming
    f2()  # f2 must be executed after f1()
```

f1() is very expensive in time. f2() must be executed after f1().
I wanted to use multiprocessing to speed up f1(), so I revise test():

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Pool


def test():
    pool = Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count())
    res = [pool.apply_async(f1, (p)) for p in list_pars]
    # 
    # ??? pause or what?
    # 
    f2()  # f2 must be executed after f1()
```

f1() is speed up, but f2() is executed before f1() is completed.
How to let the program wait a bit? It shall start executing f2() after finishing f1(). How shall I revise the codes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use some sort of thread synchronization ? [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914828/python-multiprocessing-pool-join-not-waiting-to-go-on) and [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-in-python-set-2-synchronization/)

I would write `pool.join()`

Comment: Thank you so much!