# Python 3.9: multiprocessing process start() got an error| TypeError: cannot pickle 'weakref' object

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to decrease running time by using multiprocessing.
I got a weird error `TypeError: cannot pickle 'weakref' object`
I'm not quite sure why this error occurs because I also use this approach to run another program but it run normally. Can someone explain why this error occurs.
I already follow this [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914828/python-multiprocessing-pool-join-not-waiting-to-go-on) but it did not work for me.

```py
import multiprocessing
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
class T_TestFeature:
    def __init__(self, data, classes):
        self.data = data
        self.classes = classes 
        self.manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
        self.pval = self.manager.list()
        
    def preform(self):
        process = []
        for i in range(10):
            process.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=self.t_test, args=(i,)))

        for p in process:
            p.start()

        for p in process:
            p.join()

    def t_test(self, k):
        index_samples = np.array(self.data)[:,k]
        rs1 = [index_samples[i] for i in range(len(index_samples)) if self.classes[i] == "Virginia"]
        rs2 = [index_samples[i] for i in range(len(index_samples)) if self.classes[i] != "Virginia"]
        self.pval.append(stats.ttest_ind(rs1, rs2, equal_var=False).pvalue)

def main():
    df = pd.read_excel("/Users/xxx/Documents/Project/src/flattened.xlsx")
    flattened = df.values.T
    y = df.columns
    result = T_TestFeature(flattened, y)
    result.preform()
    print(result.pval)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxx/Documents/Project/src/t_test.py", line 41, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/xxx/Documents/Project/src/t_test.py", line 37, in main
    result.preform()
  File "/Users/xxx/Documents/Project/src/t_test.py", line 21, in preform
    p.start()
  File "/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/context.py", line 284, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 32, in __init__
    super().__init__(process_obj)
  File "/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 19, in __init__
    self._launch(process_obj)
  File "/Users/x/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 47, in _xxlaunch
    reduction.dump(process_obj, fp)
  File "/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle 'weakref' object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simpler way to reproduce your issue:

```
from multiprocessing import Manager, Process


class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.manager = Manager()

    def start(self):
        print("started")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = A()
    proc = Process(target=a.start)
    proc.start()
    proc.join()
```

You cannot pickle instances containing manager objects, because they contain reference to the manager process they started (therefore, in general you can't pickle instances containing objects of class `Process`).

A simple fix would be to not store the manager. It will automatically be garbage collected once no references to the managed list remains:

```
def __init__(self, data, classes):
    self.data = data
    self.classes = classes
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    self.pval = manager.list()
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for the answer‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️. I have drill down to the problem that why it can't pickle the process and it is about those low level thing which I completely forgot‍♂️. And I have a conclusion that when we running program (Process1) to create another process (Process2), if we want to communicate with Process2 we can not communicate (we can not reference to another process's memory) directly because 'process don't share memory' means it need something like pipe or manager to help process communicate together (I think it like a medium). Feel free to discuss my conclusions.